# Javascript: create font from blob data

Tags: javascript, fonts, blob, loading, assets

I'm trying to create an assets loader based on XMLHttpRequest only. I'm loading images with the help of XMLHttpRequest, getting it's responce of "blob" type and converting it to a normal html element. Something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var image;
var blob;
request.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            blob = request.response;
            image = new Image();
            image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }
    }
};
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.open("GET", "resource_url", true);
request.send();
```

I want to implement the same conception for loading fonts and registering them on the page after loaded. It it posible in general? What should I do with blob responce after it is received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you'll need to switch to CSS for this, as that's the only way of loading fonts into a page currently (the [Font Loading API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API) is on its way, but has almost zero support right now).

In CSS, custom font declaration looks something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Yo Font";
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAA...) format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

How exactly your `font-face` declaration looks depends on the type of fonts you're loading. More info in the MDN CSS spec for [font-face here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

This means that you'll have to create a stylesheet dynamically, using it to load your fonts. You have two methods for updating the stylesheet.

1. Dynamically updating the rules of the stylesheet via the [StyleSheet DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet) (most efficient method), you'd get your `StyleSheet` object with `styleElement.stylesheet`
2. Appending your `font-face` declarations to the `innerHTML` of a `<style />` element.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that I can append my blob data converted by the _createObjectURL_ method to the _@font-face **src**_ propery?

Comment: @StanislauHerasimovich That's correct, essentially.